# start with different url in angularjs/phonegap

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to understand the execution flow of angularjs/phonegap. I have 2 views: one is list view another is detail view. When the app is started the first time, the list view is shown first, user then selects which list item and show detail view which is recorded in localStorage. When the app is started next time, it should show the detail view directly without showing list view first. I use the following code and is working except when the app is started next time, the list view is shown first then quickly detail view is shown.

index.html:

```
  <!-- Libs -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>

  <!-- App -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/routers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      app.initialize();
  </script>
```

index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        //handle backbutton to exit app when on homepage
        document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e){
            if(window.location.hash == '#/users' || window.location.hash == '#' || window.location.hash == ''){
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else {
                navigator.app.backHistory()
            }
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        //app.startPage();    //listview then detailview
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            //app.startPage();                         //listview only
            angular.module('userdemo', []);
            //app.startPage();                           //listview only
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['userdemo']);
            //app.startPage();                           //listview only
        });
        app.startPage();     //listview then detailview. if remove "route otherwise clause", show blank listview then detail template view, backbutton working
    },
    // decide which page to start with
    startPage: function() {
        var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
        if(!userId) window.location.hash = '/users';
        else window.location.hash = '/users/' + userId;
    }
};
```

routers.js:

```
angular.module('userdemo', ['userdemoFilters', 'userdemoServices']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/users',{
          templateUrl: 'partials/user-grid.html',
          controller: UserGridCtrl
      }).
      when('/users/:userId', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/user-detail.html',
          controller: UserDetailCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo:    //if removed, it shows black screen. backbutton working
          '/users'             //normal
          //'/users/3'          //show detail template only. backbutton not working
          /*
          function(routeParams, path, search) {          //show detail template only. backbutton not working
              var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
              if(!userId) return '/users';
              else return '/users/' + userId;
          }*/
          });
}])
    .run(function($location) {            //listview then detailview. if remove "otherwise" clause, blank screen, backbutton not working
        //var userId = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
        //if(!userId) $location.hash('/users');
        //else $location.hash('/users/' + userId);
});
```

UserDetailControl():

```
function UserDetailCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, User) {
    //handle the case when the app is started from the last saved userId
    if(!$rootScope.users)
        $scope.users = User.query(function() {
            for (var i=0; i<$scope.users.length; i++) {
                var user = $scope.users[i];
                if(!user.id) user.id = i;
            }
            $rootScope.users = $scope.users;
        });
    else
        $scope.users = $rootScope.users;

    $scope.user = $rootScope.users[$routeParams.userId];
}
```

user-detail.html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div>
        <b>Hello {{user.name}}</b><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried other possible alternatives:

1. remove "route otherwise clause". It shows blank listview then detail template view without scope applied(that is, literally, Hello {{user.name}}).
2. put app.startPage() in different places. around, inside, before, after document.ready or angular.bootstrap call. If around document.ready, it shows listview then detailview. If inside document.ready, it shows listview only.
3. write a custom "route otherwise redirectTo" function as shown in commented code. The result shows detail template only without scope applied. Also backbutton not working.
4. put initialization code inside module.run() as shown in commented  code. It shows listview then detailview. If remove "otherwise" clause, blank screen, backbutton not working.
5. Not change others, just replace "route otherwise redirectTo" from "/users" to "/users/3", it shows detail template view only. backbutton not working.

None of them shows what I want. Can someone expert on Angular/Phonegap explain why these happen to better understand mechanism behind? What is the right solution for showing the detail view only for app's next start?

Comment: From what I can tell you've tried setting the location value in the run() function and it didn't work? That is what I would have tried first anyways. It also sounds like you want the back button to work here. I've played with Android webkit apps before (using Trigger.io not phonegap) and assuming you have not stopped the app it should keep the state from the last time it was opened, it shouldn't have to bootstrap itself again.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it would be safer to attach the `backbutton` listener *after* the `deviceready` event is fired. [Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton)

Answer (score 1):

You may set the angular routs dynamically after loading phonegap and checking the local-storage, and before manually bootstraping angular..

`otherwise({redirectTo:SOME_DYNAMIC_VALUE})`

Comment: I already tried what you said and it does not do what expected. Please read my question carefully.